# Change color of footer iand background n SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

How to add custom color to the footer in SharePoint online as well as the background? The footer seems to take the color of the primary theme, however we want the theme color to be different from the footer. You can customize a lot of other color properties for the theme, and what other color-properties does the footer use except for the primary main theme?

Comment: Please refer to the article: http://jenkinsblogs.com/2018/12/03/how-to-modify-the-page-header-background-color/

Answer (score 1):

I read through this article when I tried to do the same thing and it helped allot.

https://laurakokkarinen.com/how-to-create-a-multicolored-theme-for-a-modern-sharepoint-online-site/